# Find angle between two vectors relative to a normal

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I'm making a simulation which requires random movement and sometimes requires homing to some points. I do the movement through random angles and need the same principle for homing towards a point. However I don't know how to find the angle between two vectors A and B with B having a normal going downwards. Something like this.
$\hskip 2 in$[image]

Comment: angle between two points?

Comment: @AjayMishra Sorry 2 given vectors.

Comment: Are you familiar with this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: calculate the dot product, it is also equal to product of magnitudes and cosine of the angle between the vectors. Solve for cosine.

Comment: @MeteHanKahraman Thanks this worked out!!!